# Como llamar a función con parámetros diferentes con botones dinámicos con tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

tengo una porcion de codigo en mi frame en el cual creo una serie de botones en base a un resultado de una consulta

```
try:
  cursor=conexion.execute("select codigo,titulo,leido,aceptado,direActual,direDestino,pasajero,fecha from mensajes")
  c=1
  for fila in cursor:
      if(fila[2]==1):
        lblTit=Button(frMensajes,text=fila[1],command=lambda:abrirMensaje(fila[2]),bg='#CF9F24',fg='black',font=('Roboto Mono',25,'bold'),width='36')
        lblTit.grid(row=c,column=0,sticky=W,pady=10)
        c=c+1     
except sqlite3.OperationalError:
    print("Error al recuperar todas las filas :"+ str(sqlite3.OperationalError))    
conexion.close()
```

el boton funciona y abro la funcion *abriMensaje* el inconveniente esta en que siempre le llega el ultimo valor almacenado en `fila[2]` independientemente de que boton apriete.

Alguna sugerencia? desde ya muchas gracias

PD: es con python y tkinter (sin usar clases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explicación

Cuando tu lambda se ejecuta, busca la variable "fila" fuera del propio lambda.

El bucle for va obteniendo cada item de la lista y lo guarda en la variable "fila".
Entonces, una vez salgas del bucle for, la variable fila tendrá el ultimo valor que el bucle for obtuvo.
En tu caso, el bucle for acaba el recorrido del iterable y el ultimo valor que guardó en fila va a ser la ultima fila.

Esto lo puedes ver bien ilustrado en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
for i in range(50):
    pass

print(i)
```

Tu lambda obtiene la variable global fila, cuyo valor será siempre el valor de la ultima fila.

#### Solución

En lo personal, yo soluciono este tipo de problemas creando una función que cree tu lambda.
Esta forma funciona por que el lambda busca la variable dentro del ámbito de la función, en lugar de buscarla en el ámbito global.

Advertencia: No pude probar el código, pero yo creo que funcionará. Si no funciona dime!

```
def crear_funcion(fila2):
    return lambda:abrirMensaje(fila2)

try:
    cursor=conexion.execute("select codigo,titulo,leido,aceptado,direActual,direDestino,pasajero,fecha from mensajes")
    c=1
    for fila in cursor:
        if(fila[2]==1):
            lblTit=Button(frMensajes,text=fila[1],command=crear_funcion(fila[2]),bg='#CF9F24',fg='black',font=('Roboto Mono',25,'bold'),width='36')
            lblTit.grid(row=c,column=0,sticky=W,pady=10)
            c=c+1
            
except sqlite3.OperationalError:
    print("Error al recuperar todas las filas :"+ str(sqlite3.OperationalError))
    conexion.close()
```

#### Un consejo adicional

En lugar de crear una variable que inicie con un numero especifico y sumarle 1 puedes usar la función built-in [enumerate](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumerate-in-python/). Que crea algo equivalente a esto [(numero inicial, fila1), (numero inicial+1, fila2), ...], el numero inicial por default es 0.
Junto a esto podemos [desempaquetar](https://stackabuse.com/unpacking-in-python-beyond-parallel-assignment) esto en dos variables.

Tu código aplicando esto quedaría así:

```
def crear_funcion(fila2):
    return lambda:abrirMensaje(fila2)

try:
    cursor=conexion.execute("select codigo,titulo,leido,aceptado,direActual,direDestino,pasajero,fecha from mensajes")

    for c, fila in enumerate(cursor):
        if(fila[2]==1):
            lblTit=Button(frMensajes,text=fila[1],command=crear_funcion(fila[2]),bg='#CF9F24',fg='black',font=('Roboto Mono',25,'bold'),width='36')
            lblTit.grid(row=c,column=0,sticky=W,pady=10)
            
except sqlite3.OperationalError:
    print("Error al recuperar todas las filas :"+ str(sqlite3.OperationalError))
    conexion.close()
```

Comment: Disculpa la tardanza, efectivamente soluciono lo que comente, gracias por tu tiempo y explicación. muchas gracias