# ¿Por qué el comando de los botones se sobreescribe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

quiero crear una función que genere botones y los asigne a distintas funciones que tengo creadas. Para ello creo una tupla donde almaceno los datos necesarios para seleccionar el texto que tiene que tener el botón y la función que pasar como comando. Lo hace todo bien, pero los comandos de todos los botones siempre se sobreescriben por el del último que se ha creado.

Esta es la función:

```py
def crear_botones(raiz):

    tupla = creartuplanombresvar()

    for i in tupla:
        Button(raiz, text=nombres[i[0]][0], command=lambda:nombres[i[0]][1](i[1])).pack()
```

nombres es un diccionario donde almaceno los nombres de los botones y la función que ejecuta cada uno y la tupla contiene tuplas en las que por parejas van la clave del diccionario y las variables que recibe la función. Es una cosa así: `(((clave1),(variables1)),((clave2),(variables2)))`.

He probado a ejecutar el programa sin usar el lambda en el comando y en cada iteración usa la función correcta pero luego cuando pulso el botón no hace nada.

Comment: Responde esto a tu pregunta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/457264/como-llamar-a-funci%c3%b3n-con-par%c3%a1metros-diferentes-con-botones-din%c3%a1micos-con-tkinte/457271#457271

Comment: En tu caso, en ves de ser la variable fila, es la variable i

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya me sirvió!!