# Problema con botones y funciones en Python Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Tengo el siguiente código y al darle click a los botones generados por un **for** siempre me imprime el ultimo valor de la lista el **"click 5"**, ¿Cómo podría hacer para que me imprima los valores de la lista dependiendo del botón al que le haga click y no me de siempre el ultimo valor de la lista?, de ante mano agradezco la ayuda de quien responda y también si tienen una mejor forma de realizar este código les estaría muy agradecido

```
from tkinter import *



root = Tk()
mi_lista = ['click 1', 'click 2', 'click 3', 'click 4', 'click 5']


def mostrar(nombre):
    print(nombre)


for i in range(len(mi_lista)):
    Button(root, text=mi_lista[i], command=lambda: mostrar(mi_lista[i])).grid(row=i, column=0)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Te está pasando lo mismo que al autor de esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/457264/como-llamar-a-funci%c3%b3n-con-par%c3%a1metros-diferentes-con-botones-din%c3%a1micos-con-tkinte/457271#457271 con la variable i

Comment: waaa!!! Dante S. muchas gracias enserio!!! me ayudo mucho, aun que es una forma un tanto curiosa de resolverlo pero enserio muchas gracias!!