# ¿Cómo asignar una función lambda a varios botones al mismo tiempo? Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy diseñando mi primera interfaz básica en Python 3.8 (usando el módulo tkinter), y quiero que en lugar de **repetir la función enlazada para cada botón**, pueda hacer que todos los botones tomen esa función (en este caso, `command = self.windows`) sin tener que repetir el código muchas veces. ¿Esto es posible? Muchas gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.Se los agradezco.

```py
def creator(self):
    lst = []
    arg1, arg2, = 0, 1,
    for i in range(23):   
        btn = Button(self, text='buttons')#
              #command=lambda: self.windows(
              #lambda top1: Class1(top1, i, arg1, arg2, path),
              #lambda top2: Class2(top2, i, arg1, arg2, path),
              #lambda top3: Class3(top3, i, arg1, arg2, path)))
        lst.append(btn)
    
    lst[0].config(command=lambda: self.windows(
               lambda top1: Class1(top1, 0, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top2: Class2(top2, 0, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top3: Class3(top3, 0, arg1, arg2, path)))
    
    lst[1].config(command=lambda: self.windows(
               lambda top1: Class1(top1, 1, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top2: Class2(top2, 1, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top3: Class3(top3, 1, arg1, arg2, path)))

    lst[2].config(command=lambda: self.windows(
               lambda top1: Class1(top1, 2, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top2: Class2(top2, 2, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top3: Class3(top3, 2, arg1, arg2, path)))

    lst[3].config(command=lambda: self.windows(
               lambda top1: Class1(top1, 3, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top2: Class2(top2, 3, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top3: Class3(top3, 3, arg1, arg2, path)))

    lst[4].config(command=lambda: self.windows(
               lambda top1: Class1(top1, 4, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top2: Class2(top2, 4, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top3: Class3(top3, 4, arg1, arg2, path)))

    lst[5].config(command=lambda: self.windows(
               lambda top1: Class1(top1, 5, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top2: Class2(top2, 5, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top3: Class3(top3, 5, arg1, arg2, path)))

    lst[6].config(command=lambda: self.windows(
               lambda top1: Class1(top1, 6, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top2: Class2(top2, 6, arg1, arg2, path),
               lambda top3: Class3(top3, 6, arg1, arg2, path)))
```

Comment: Por lo que veo intentaste hacer algo así. Pero probablemente te chocaste con que el i que le pasas al class1, 2 y 3 era siempre el ultimo del bucle for (22) sin importar que boton presionases. Quizá esta pregunta te sirva: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/457264/como-llamar-a-funci%c3%b3n-con-par%c3%a1metros-diferentes-con-botones-din%c3%a1micos-con-tkinte/457271#457271. Podrías decirme luego de leerla si te sirvió o no porfa?

Comment: @DanteS Funciono tu recomendación, pero estas seguro que es una forma correcta y eficiente de hacerlo, por lo demás todo bien porque soluciono mi problema. Gracias

Comment: Siendo sincero, no tengo idea, pero es la unica forma que conozco. Me alegro de que te sirva :D